# How to apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality on the following inner product?

Tags: vectors, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Reading a research article, I came across the following statement:

The following function (where $x_i$ and $p_j$ are two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mu_{i,j}$ is a constant) - it doesn't matter where it came from, is just an inner product actually:

$\sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} - \left< \sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}, \frac{p_j}{||p_j||}  \right>$

is minimized by using the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality iff

$p_j \propto \sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}$.

I want to apply the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality on $\left< \sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}, \frac{p_j}{||p_j||}  \right>$ in order to understand where the proportionality thing came from.

So basically the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality states that: 
$\left< x, y\right> \le ||x|| \cdot ||y||$. But how can I apply this formula on that monstrous term?

Comment: \begin{align*}\left\langle \sum_i\mu_{i,j}\frac{x_i}{\|x_i\|},\frac{p_j}{\|p_j\|}\right\rangle &= \sum_i\mu_{i,j}\left\langle\frac{x_i}{\|x_i\|},\frac{p_j}{\|p_j\|}\right\rangle
\\&= \sum_i\mu_{i,j}\frac{\langle x_i,p_j\rangle}{\|x_i\|\|p_j\|}\\&\leq\sum_i\mu_{i,j} \end{align*}

Does that help?

Comment: @user3482749 no, this is actually where the formula I stated came from (like going backwards), and it doesn't use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality, but thanks for your contribution anyway

Comment: It does use the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality: that's precisely what that inequality is.

Comment: @user3482749 I don't think this is the correct answer because as I said, in the article the equations you stated are used to generate the formula in my question. So it's like going backwards.

Comment: @user3482749 I can give you a link if this helps: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiD2oKQ0-3eAhXL26QKHZfMClAQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstatsoft.org%2Farticle%2Fview%2Fv050i10%2Fv50i10.pdf&usg=AOvVaw23krOATCBZ7DzyPzp8Y-jq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beyond the inequality itself, the full Cauchy-Schwarz theorem states that $|\langle u, v\rangle|$ is maximized exactly when $u$ and $v$ are parallel or anti-parallel. I.e., when $v \propto u$. For your inner product, this is

$$\frac{p_j}{\|p_j\|} \propto \sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}$$

Since $1/\|p_j\|$ is just a scalar multiplier, it can be absorbed into the constant of proportionality, leaving 
$$p_j \propto \sum_{i} \mu_{i,j} \frac{x_i}{||x_i||}$$